# how I can insert from hive table to partitioned table(as parquet)?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

I have hive-table and partitioned table.

I insert into partitioned table like below. It is auto create partition if it is not exists.

I run this query in impala editor.

This query takes too long time .

```
insert into   default.dw_partitioned_table
            partition (partition_islemtarih_string)
select *, cast(replace(strleft(recorddate,10),'-','')as int) as partition_islemtarih_string
from default.dw_hive_table
where recorddate <to_timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
 and  recorddate>=to_timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

I miss something or i make wrong ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your insert is slow because impala is creating partition for each date `replace(strleft(recorddate,10),'-','')` in the original table. Impala creates physical files for each partition and thats why it is very slow.
If you have large number of records and you *really really* want to distribute data over date then do this and it will take long time.
Better idea is to partition on MM-yyyy of record date - This will create evenly distributed partitions. Looking at your SQL it seems you can even distribute over yyyy as well.
Also please note static partition is way faster. For example -
`insert into t partition (part_col='2020') select * from t2 ;` - way faster because impala doesnt have to create dynamic partition.

Comment: thanks for answer, I updated my question. My partition is int. So I cant do it MM-yyyy. But 
 i can try to insert  auto created pattitioned table.

Comment: then remove - and change the key to yyyyMM all in one. This is unique too.

Comment: also pls use `cast(from_timestamp(recorddate,'yyyyMM')as int)` to be sure your partions are working properly

Comment: thanks for reply, then Can I use those partition with `between` keyword?

Comment: if you are issuing SELECT then yes. I am not sure how else you will use between. But it will act like a new table - so you can use.